# Is it possible to make a pirateplot using frequencies instead of densities in R?

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I am searching and trying the following plot in R for ages, but nothing seems to work.

What I want is a quantitative variable in the Y axis and a categorical variable in the X axis, and just an horizontal histogram (of the Y variable) for each category.

I couldn't find a package that does this. Any suggestions?

[image: Vertical histograms showing the distribution of genetic ancestry for each of the five self-perceived ancestry categories.]

Comment: ggplot2::geom_violin() would be similar, but with density estimation. Maybe that's a start?!

Comment: Thank you David, a violin plot is more appropriate description, If I can make it with frequencies I will put the code here

Comment: Check the yarr package https://github.com/ndphillips/yarrr